# Store PHP File that Makes Database Calls In or Out of the Root?

Tags: php, apache, security, document-root

I have a website that uses Ajax to make PHP calls to a database.  Simple enough.  I'd like to secure my php files from prying eyes.  I've found that I can restrict some access by setting `file_uploads=Off`, but I'd like to go a bit further.  What is the best practice for securing this file?  I'm guessing something like Appache setting, a command in the PHP file itslef (as above), or perhaps I should just move the file out of the site's root directory, but I'm just not sure.

Many thanks!

Comment: A simple google of "secure php" gives me https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet as first result, try harder please.

Comment: If it was outside of the root directory, Ajax wouldn't have access as it runs client side

Comment: Populus - I have been doing research on it.  found no concise answers.  Thanks for the booklet.  Gavin - I was concerned that might happen but I wanted confirmation that I should avoid that route.  Thanks for a constructive answer.